# Приложение падает при нажатии UP button

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

В приложении имеются три activity с фрагментами. Первый фрагмент RecyclerView со списком, второй тоже, третий фрагмент детализация предыдущего. При клике по первому списку передается id через intent и открывается второй список. Затем при клике по второму списку тоже передается id (но уже другой) через intent и открывается третья (детализированная) activity. При нажатии UP Button (в левом верхнем углу) из третьего фрагмента - приложение падает. В Stacktrace NullPointer Exception - отсутствует id для второй activity (родительской по отношению к третьей). Хотя при нажатии Back Button всё отображается и работает нормально. Каким образом мне получить этот id из родительской активности и как его вставить назад при нажатии UP Button?

Стартуем родительскую

```
public void onClick(View view){
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
            Department department = mDepartments.get(position);
            int deptId = department.getId();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(DEPARTMENT_ID, deptId);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CoworkersActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Родительская activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_coworkers);

    if (savedInstanceState == null){

        CoworkersFragment fragment = CoworkersFragment
                .newInstance(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(DepartmentAdapter.ViewHolder.DEPARTMENT_ID));

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.coworkers_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Стартуем из адаптера родительской activity детализированную с фрагментом

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
            Employee employee = mEmployees.get(position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(ARG_EMPLOYEE, employee);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: У Вас в `Bundle` объект типа `Employee`, а извлекаете значение Вы методом `getInt(...)`.

Comment: И почему Вы не пользуетесь напрямую методом `Intent.putExtra(String name, Serializable value)`?

Comment: Не совсем понятно описал, добавил немного кода

Comment: `NPE` на какой строке?

Comment: `.newInstance(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(DepartmentAdapter.ViewHolder.DEPARTMENT_ID));`

Comment: А каковы результаты вызовов `getIntent()` и `getIntent().getExtras()`?

Comment: Вопрос про использование `Bundle` остался актуален: почему Вы его используете? Можно же напрямую `Intent.putExtra(String name, int value)` и `getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)`.

Comment: Что-то я все равно не понял, Вы говорите, что приложение падает при нажатии кнопки, однако `NPE` у Вас в `onCreate(...)`.

Comment: Переделал без `Bundle`, стало работать, но только из-за того что при получении значения `getIntExtra` имеется дефолтное значение, оно то и вставляется. А при вызове `getIntent().getExtras()` передается id и `getIntent()` тоже работает

Comment: Так и получается, что значения имеются, всё работает. Вот только при возврате к родительской activity по нажатию UP button NPE выпадает

Answer (score 1):

каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку UP создавался новый instance activity без параметров, что провоцировало NPE, для того чтобы activity открывалась в том состоянии которое было, в манифесте для нее надо прописать атрибут `android:launchMode="singleTop"`